# Webservice caching Token

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, php, web-services

I am using a LAMP server. No matter what token the service call has, it's always showing me the same number. Right now it's 2147483647.I guess it changes if I reboot server.

I have other values in the service call. All other are correct except the token.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All I know is that is the maximum value for a 32-bit signed integer.  It probably won't change when you reboot.  Can you please go into more detail as to what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It is solved, it was int overflow issue. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php